# python2 can't file a file in current folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

For the next file info:

```
[jzun@hscd8a25e93f9vm dates]$ pwd

/home/jzun/vivo_mod_samples/dates

[jzun@hscd8a25e93f9vm dates]$ ls

date_def.json  dates_add.rdf  dates.bak  dates.rdf  dates_sub.rdf  dates.txt      datetime_precision_enum.txt  gen_date_rdf.py  gen_date_rdf.py.bak  gen_dates.py  gen_dates.py.bak  get.txt  README.md  run_pump_2_to_create_date_defs.sh  sv.cfg
```

I have the next python2 function:

```
def read_csv(filename, skip=True, delimiter='|'):
   """
   Read a CSV file, return dictionary object
   :param filename: name of file to read
   :param skip: should lines with invalid number of columns be skipped?  False=Throw Exception
   :param delimiter: The delimiter for CSV files
   :return: Dictionary object
   """
cwd = os.getcwd()

print("read_csv>current dir = " + cwd)

# fp = open(filename, 'rU')

# print(fp)

# data = read_csv_fp(fp, skip, delimiter)
# fp.close()

with open(filename, 'rU') as fp:
    data = read_csv_fp(fp, skip, delimiter)
    fp.close()
    
return data
```

After running it with filename = dates.txt I get the next result:

```
read_csv>current dir = /home/jzun/vivo_mod_samples/dates
dates.txt file not found
```

I know similar questions have been posted but interestingly I can not find anything that could help me to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: How about doing a join? `file_path= os.path.join(cwd, file_name)` and then `with open(file_path, 'rU') as fp`

Comment: Notice how `dates.txt` has a lot more space after it than the other filenames in your `ls` output?  I suspect it's actually named `dates.txt    `, with some trailing spaces as part of the name.  You can try `print(os.listdir('.'))` to see what the actual filenames are in the current directory.

Comment: @jasonharper, good point. I added an assert to double check that the file exist.

Comment: I checked the code again following your suggestions and I found that the read_csv_fp function was the one generating the error but the file was being opened as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the full path of the file `dates.txt`:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
file_name = "dates.txt"
file_path = os.path.join(cwd, file_name)

# Double check that file exist
assert os.path.isfile(file_path) is True

with open(file_path, 'rU') as fp:
    data = read_csv_fp(fp, skip, delimiter)
    fp.close()
```